# C2248 error when compiling a CLR enabled C++ project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 from Visual Studio 2010. My solution builds fine in Visual Studio 2010. However in Visual Studio 2012, a CLR enabled C++ project throws c2248 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject' from an export class below. If I comment out AFX_CLASS_EXPORT for CParmArray, the project compiles without error. Or if I turn off CLR support, it also compiles without error. But these are not options since other projects in the solution will get link error when building.

What has changed in Visual Studio 2012 that could cause the problem? How do I correct the error?

I appreciate any advice.

compiler output:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h(262): error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(559) : see declaration of 'CObject::CObject'
 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afx.h(534) : see declaration of 'CObject'
 1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CArray<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>::CArray(const CArray<TYPE,ARG_TYPE> &)'
 1>          with
 1>          [
 1>              TYPE=int *,
 1>              ARG_TYPE=int *&
 1>          ]
```

code:

```
class AFX_CLASS_EXPORT CParmArray : public CArray<int, int* &>
{
public:
  CParmArray();
  CParmArray(const CParmArray& testArray);
  void operator=(const CParmArray& testArray);
  virtual ~CParmArray();
};
```

Comment: This is a *very* common error.  It is intentional, it prevents you from copying a CObject derived object.  So giving the CParam a copy constructor is a lost cause.  Just google the error message to find many hits.

Comment: @Hans Passant, CParm has a copy constructor. I tried adding a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to CParmArray. It does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the CArray class with a derived class that implements the copy contructors. It works fine in my DLL with clr support.

```
  class AFX_CLASS_EXPORT CArrayEx : public CArray
 {
   public:
    CArrayEx()
   {
   }
   protected:
    CArrayEx(const CArrayEx& objectSrc);// with empty implementation
};
```